# CanvasJS not showing on iOS

Tags: canvasjs

When I run my app on a browser of my local machine (ionic serve) to test, I see the column chart perfectly as designed for both android and ios.

When I simulate on Android, the chart still shows up.

When I simulate on iPhone, nothing.

I made a mistake uploading this on AppStore.

If it helps, I now have the commercial license.

Comment: I think you are loading canvasjs file from local, which works file when you run locally or in emulator in same machine. But when you run it in iPhone, may be it fails to load canvasjs.min.js (file-path may not be proper) because of which it may be failing to render charts. Check the file path of canvasjs library in your code.